# Get exported semantic model for MetadataReference

Tags: .net, roslyn

Is it possible to get a collection of ITypeSymbol's for the types exported by an assembly that's been added to a compilation as a MetadataReference?

I want to inspect the types available to the referencing project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `Compilation.GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol()` for each MetadataReference, cast to `IAssemblySymbol`, then look at the `TypeNames` property (which returns strings).

To get the actual `ITypeSymbol`s for each type, fetch the assembly's `GlobalNamespace`, then recursively crawl through `GetMembers()` (which includes both types and nested namespaces).  You can inherit a [`SymbolVisitor<IEnumerable<ITypeSymbol>>`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/SymbolVisitor%25601.cs) to help with the recursion (especially for nested types).