# How can I look up custom attributes for a class

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to use Roslyn API (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) for loading an assembly and looking up the custom attributes. Code I have so far is:

```
var assembly =  MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(tempFileName);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(null).AddReferences(assembly);
var assemblySymbol = (IAssemblySymbol)compilation.GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol(assembly);

var globalNamespace = assemblySymbol.GlobalNamespace.GetAttributes();
```

But GetAttributes() is empty.

Can Roslyn even do this? Am I going about it the right way?

Comment: For a class? Why are you calling `GetAttributes()` on `GlobalNamespace` then?

Comment: How do I get the attributes for a class then? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know all classes with a certain attribute or all defined attributes within the assembly?

Comment: Certain attribute for a class within the assembly. I need to check if that attribute exists and read the attribute to retrieve some specific info. I used to do this using mono.cecil in 4.6.2 framework, but mono.cecil does not work for .Net core. Thanks.

Comment: @VKR, if you want to achieve it using **Roslyn** just look at the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914240/get-exported-semantic-model-for-metadatareference/32937808#32937808), at the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37327692/5359302) and at the [simple example](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6138#issuecomment-149216303). This examples retrieve all containing types in a compilation, so you just need to get from all of them their `Attributes` and check they as you wish